# Installing gnome-browser-connector removes ubuntu-desktop in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, 23.10

Why does installing gnome-browser-connector result in the removal of all desktops (ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-desktop-minimal, ubuntu-gnome-desktop)?  Wouldn't this break most desktops?

I understand that gnome-browser-connector replaces chrome-gnome-shell.

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-browser-connector
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-cantarell gir1.2-gnomeautoar-0.1 xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  chrome-gnome-shell policykit-1-gnome
Suggested packages:
  chromium | chromium-browser
Recommended packages:
  gnome-shell-extension-prefs
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gdm3 gnome-session gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-tiling-assistant ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-session
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chrome-gnome-shell gnome-browser-connector policykit-1-gnome
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 10 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 41.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,128 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Chrome and Firefox are installed:

```
$ dpkg-query -l | grep google-chrome
ii  google-chrome-stable                       119.0.6045.105-1                        amd64        The web browser from Google

$ dpkg-query -l | grep firefox
ii  firefox                                    1:1snap1-0ubuntu3                       amd64        Transitional package - firefox -> firefox snap
```